# how to restore to original CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The site is this:
http://roobvillalobos.ga/

I change the CSS with this code:

```
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function(){
     { $(".numero").css("display", "none"); }
     { $(".subtitulo").css("font-size", "1em"); }
     { $("h1").css("font-size", "1.3em"); }
 });
</script>
```

But I don´t know how restore to the original CSS when I be on top again

Comment: Would be easier if you create CSS classes, then you can just toggle them with jQuery.

Comment: Just comment the whole script tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set it to an empty string again, and it will use the CSS stylesheet.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var topDistance = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (topDistance == 0) {
        $(".numero").css("display", ""); 
        $(".subtitulo").css("font-size", ""); 
        $("h1").css("font-size", "");
    }
});
```

Of course, this assumes that these elements did not have any inline styles before you messed with them. Otherwise, you'll have to keep them in a variable and re-apply them later.

Comment: Thanks, but how use the code to indicate when I be on the TOP again.

I mean, the first script is when I scroll the mouse.
But I don´t know how restore when return to the TOP

Comment: You can check that with an `if` inside the function. `$('body').scrollTop() == 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this problem differently. You can add a class to the body when you scroll down the page. And you can remove the same class when you scroll to the top of the page.

Let's say we call this class "scrolled". You can rewrite the javascript as

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if($('body').scrollTop() > 0) 
    $('body').addClass('scrolled');
  else
    $('body').removeClass('scrolled');
});
```

In your stylesheet or inline style, you can define

```
/* Case: Page scrolled to top */
.numero { display: <top value>; }
.subtitulo { font-size: <top value>; }
h1 {font-size : <top value>; }

/* Case: Page scrolled down */
body.scrolled .numero { display:none; }
body.scrolled .subtitulo { font-size: 1em; }
body.scrolled h1 {font-size : 1.3em; }
```